# dynamic table in c# for database rows

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `table` with a column  called `totalnames`.This table has 10 rows.

Now i want to dynamically create table for this 10 rows with check box in my web page.Please send some good examples.

Comment: You should try it your self first, SO will help you only when you will get stuck at some point. Remember God help those who help them self.

Answer (score 0):

**Sample Code** : Dynamically create table, add cloumn, add rows

```
(1) create a new DataTable 
    DataTable dt = new DataTable ("Table_AX"); 

(2) Add columns to the DataTable 
    // Method 1 
    dt.Columns.Add ("column0", System.Type.GetType ("System.String")); 
    // Method 2 
    DataColumn dc = new DataColumn ("column1", System.Type.GetType ("System.Boolean")); 
    dt.Columns.Add (dc); 

(3) to add rows to the DataTable 
    // Initialize the row 
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow (); 
    dr ["column0"] = "AX"; 
    dr ["column1"] = true; 
    dt.Rows.Add (dr); 
    // Doesn't initialize the row 
    DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow (); 
    dt.Rows.Add (dr1);
```

If you want to  Copy DataTable include data try

```
DataTable dtNew = dt.Copy ();
```